# Aerospike vs. SeaweedFS?

Tags: database, nosql, key, cql, aerospike

[Aerospike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerospike_(database)) is a (mostly commercial) distributed key value NoSQL database.

[SeaweedFS](https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs) is a (open source) distributed file system that is [based on Facebook’s Haystack design paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Beaver.pdf) that enables you to store and retrieve billions of files very quickly. It also offers data replication with rack and data center awareness, automatic data expiration (TTL) and automatically re balances data when a node fails.

How does Aerospike & SeaweedFS differ from a practical or use-case perspective? What functionality is present in Aerospike that is lacking in SeaweedFS?

Some of the other `NoSQ`L databases (such as ScyllaDB) offer `SQL` like syntax (`CQL`) so I get how they might differ from a distributed file system like SeaweedFS. But Aerospike offers none of that. It simply  stores & retrieves data based on a key. This seems super similar to how one might retrieve data in a DFS (the tech term might be different but the concept is the same).

I think this question can be more generalized: What’s the difference between a DFS and a distributed/scalable `NoSQL` key value store? However, since there are so many nuances between the various NoSQL databases, I’m using Aerospike to as an example to help illustrate the question more clearly.

Comment: I am not familiar with SeaweedFS but just wanted to mention that Aerospike is actually much more than a NoSQL key value store... it does support SQL (through Trino for example) and has a bunch of connectors that makes it suitable for a variety of use cases. Here is a high level description of Aerospike's capabilities: https://aerospike.com/products/real-time-data-platform/ .